# Magento web service returning complexarray when upgraded from 1.6 to 1.9.3``

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

To use the magento web api in visual studio I added the web service reference:

```
https://www.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl
```

I was importing order information correctly using

```
mageservice.salesOrderInfo(sessionId, orderId);
```

I then upgraded magento from v1.6.0.0 to v1.9.3.0. I am now unable to get the item information for the order. When checking via fiddler I get the following:

```
<items>
    <complexObjectArray/>
    <complexObjectArray/>
    <complexObjectArray/>
    <complexObjectArray/>
</items>
```

So instead of getting the item/product information I am getting `<complexObjectArray />` instead. How can I resolve this issue and get the item/product information?

I do get the other order information such as total info and customer / address info. But what I do not get is the `<items>` info and the `<status_history>` info.

Thank you.

EDIT: In the system.log everytime I run the API I get about 5 of those lines. About one for each `complexObjectArray` in the response.

```
2016-11-17T18:12:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array to string conversion/var/www/html/gmw.com/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the file mentioned

```
/var/www/html/gmw.com/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php
```

In the following method:

```
public function processingMethodResult(array $result) {

    foreach ($result as &$row) {
        if (!is_null($row) && !is_bool($row) && !is_numeric($row)) {
            $row = $this->processingRow($row);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I changed it to the one below and it worked

```
public function processingMethodResult(array $result) {
    foreach ($result as &$row) {
        if (is_array($row)) {  // added this if statement
            foreach ($row as &$subrow) {
                $subrow = $this->processingRow($subrow);
            }
        } else if (!is_null($row) && !is_bool($row) && !is_numeric($row)) {

            $row = $this->processingRow($row);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```